# How do I place a multidimensional array from a .txt file into code and print out one line at a time?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
<object1><object2><object3>
Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
```

The file actually contains about 50 columns and over 500K rows.

I am creating a program that duplicates this information to another text file with a momentary pause between each line print.

my trouble is that I am confused as to how to bring the info in, and print out 1 line at a time to the new text file.

I know how to open and read the original file.  I know how to create a new file and put the data in. and I know how to slow it down.  But as you can tell,  I am new to C++ and programming in general and I am trying to better understand arrays.    To be clear, this is not for a class or any homework, im just a generally confused dude haha.

Comment: `struct record { value1 v1, value2 v2; value3 v3; };` and `std::vector<record>;`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: If you just pass through lines from one file to another, you could use `fgets` and `fputs` line by line

Comment: @Muscampester You obviously didn't read....im not a student.  I am self learning coding.  but thanks for the constructive comment.

Comment: @StephanLechner Thanks, ill give that a shot after some research

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to transfer a file line by line to another file, this could look as follows:

```
char line[1000];
while (fgets(line,1000,infile)) {

  // wait or do anything needed in between
  int rc = fputs(line,outfile);
  if (rc == EOF)
    break;
}
```

If you have to do any transformations, then change `line` accordingly before writing. Hope it helps.